# usort() Multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

This is my array: http://2of1.com/zee/ZEES%20SMS%20SERVICE.html this array contains 2 array sources.

Posts from Central Casting and Posts from Debe Waisman Casting.

Right now i am getting all of the central casting posts first. Then the Debe Waisman Casting posts. like so...

central casting posts
central casting posts
central casting posts
central casting posts
central casting posts

Debe Waisman Casting posts

Debe Waisman Casting posts
Debe Waisman Casting posts
Debe Waisman Casting posts
Debe Waisman Casting posts
I want to sort these posts by their $updated_time so the newest posts are posted at the top using usort() but i am not sure how to use this function.

This is how i am getting the data from the array:

```
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->AsArray();

        foreach ($graphObject as $keyEntry => $entry){

            foreach( $entry->data as $data ) {
                $string = $data->message;
                $pic = $data->picture;
                $post_id = $data->id;
                $page_name = $data->from->name;
                $time_posted = $data->created_time;
                $updated_time = $data->updated_time;
                $unixtime = strtotime($time_posted);
                $unixtime2 = strtotime($updated_time);


                foreach( $data->actions as $action ) {
                   $link = $action->link;
                  }

                echo '<div class='posts'>$string</div>';
             }
        }
```

Comment: baring this syntax error echo '<div class='posts'>$string</div>';  where are you putting this data? you just put them in variables and forget about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I would fix this

```
echo '<div class='posts'>$string</div>';
```

So that it is this way

```
echo "<div class='posts'>$string</div>";
```

Or this way

```
echo '<div class="posts">'.$string.'</div>';
```

Than you will want to actually create an array of data you can apply the usort to, so in your loops do something like this

```
$row['updated_time'] =  $data->updated_time;
$rows[] = $row;
```

Then when you have an array such as this

```
 array(
   array( 'updated_time'=>126154655,... ),
   array(...)
)
```

you can use usort like this

```
 usort( $array, function($a,$b){
      return $a['updated_time'] < $b['updated_time'] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

So something like this

```
$rows = array();
foreach ($graphObject as $keyEntry => $entry){
    $row = array();
    foreach( $entry->data as $data ) {
        $row['string'] = $data->message;
        $row['pic'] = $data->picture;
        $row['post_id'] = $data->id;
        $row['page_name'] = $data->from->name;
        $row['time_posted'] = $data->created_time;
        $row['updated_time'] = $data->updated_time;
        $row['unixtime'] = strtotime($time_posted);
        $row['unixtime2'] = strtotime($updated_time);
        $row['links'] = array();

        foreach( $data->actions as $action ) {
             $row['links'][] = $action->link;
        }

         $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

usort( $rows, function($a,$b){
     return $a['updated_time'] < $b['updated_time'] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Otherwise all those variables evaporate on the next loop, you cant sort the data without first having the data.

UPDATE: as $data is used for your object `foreach($entry->data as $data )` you will want to use $rows or something else as the top level array.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line: '$data[] = $row;'

Comment: sorry my bad $data is in use as your object change it to something else like $rows.

Comment: Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: look again, you need to use $rows in usort as my updated answer shows.  Because $data is still your object and not the array of data :)

Comment: Ah yes... sorry my brain not working as well as yours :) Thank you

Comment: lol I breath php code.

Comment: Yes you are somewhat of a God in this field. Ok now i have a blank page so i think everything must be working well... How can i echo some of the data now?

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to use usort, i never thoguht to put everything in an array. Amazing lesson, thank you very much!

Comment: sure, like I said you have to have the data before you can sort it, its like marbles, you need a bag of them before you can separate the red from the blue.  Building the array is like collection all the marbles off the floor.